# How to set Page Width as default view of HTML5 PDF?

Tags: html, pdf

I use the native HTML5 PDF viewer to embed a PDF file within HTML as

```
<embed src="" width="100%" height="90%" type="application/pdf">
```

PDF file is opened with `Automatic Zoom`. Then, it is possible to select `Page Width`.

Is there a way to display the PDF file with zoom of `Page Width` by default?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `vw` and `vh`.

They stand for viewport width and viewport height respectively.

If you set the style `body { margin: 0 },` 100vw should behave the same as 100%

Example: `width:100vw`